# Image recognition ANN gives InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to tensorflow and I am getting the following error `InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range of [0, 10).  Label values: 6 6 1 3 8 9 1 1 7 9 2 9 3 3 6 4 7 1 1 5 4 1 7 1 3 3 8 6 10 4 10 2`, but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong?

The dataset is an image recognition dataset with 32 x 32 images with 3 color channels. I am trying to use a standard ANN

```
 # Shape info
 # x train shape : (73257, 32, 32, 3)
 # y train shape : (73257,)
 # 10 categorical variables

 def getModel(input_shape):
     model = Sequential([
         Flatten(input_shape = input_shape),
         Dense(32,activation = "relu", name = "layer1"),
         Dense(32,activation = "relu", name = "layer2"),
         Dense(32,activation = "relu", name = "layer"),
         Dense(10, activation = "softmax")
     ])

def compileModel(model):
    model.compile(
        optmizer = "adam",
        loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        accuracy = ["accuracy"]
    )

 model = getModel(x_train_imgs.shape[0].shape)
 compileModel(model)
 model.fit(x_train_imgs, y_train_labs)
```

At this point, I get the error. I found some posts that suggest something incorrect with the loss function. But since I haven't used one hot encoding I believe `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is correct.

Any ideas what's causing this issue?

Comment: I think you can simply minus 1 the labels' values so the label will be in valid range `[0, 10)`

Comment: The error is extremely explicit. There is a value of 10 in your labels. Your output layer is `Dense(10, ...)`. This corresponds to the labels `0-9`. If you have a `10` in your labels, this is `0-10` which is 11 labels. So either change your output layer to `Dense(11, ...)` or inspect your y_train and try to figure out why there are 10's in there.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My labels are from 1 to 10. Corresponding to the actual images representing digits 1-10. Managed to get it working by subtracting 1 from the labels, `y_train_labs = y_train_labs - 1` as suggested by @ĐinhAnhVũ